# How do I open a newly downloaded excel file in MS Excel from a button click in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a scenario where I made a request, got response data, created a .xlsx file using XLSX library. This new excel document is good, means it will open and show correct data when opened from system explorer.
But after download I have to display a pop-up like- "Your file is downloaded, Do you want to open it? " and Yes/No buttons. If user clicks on yes, that excel should open in MS Excel.

I tried windows.open, but it will not work as excel file will not open in chrome tab.

No code, as I am not getting even a single solution to this problem.

How to open that excel using button click?
More important question is, how do I make angular interact with a system explorer file?

Comment: Did you set the correct mime type when you send your generated excel file?

Comment: No, i did nothing for mime type. The generated excel is good, opening properly from excel. I am not getting any code/example on how to access this file from angular to open.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Absolute Path of the file you are trying to open

eg:

`Excel.Workbooks.Open("E:\\test.xlsx");`

Comment: Cannot find name 'Excel'; from where will it get excel?